# How do I redirect an apache2 site from a non-existent virtual folder back to the root?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, redmine

I have a redmine website.  Works like this:

```
https://redmine.domain.com/redmine
```

I've moved services to a new server and now to reach it I only do this:

```
https://redmine.domain.com
```

So, the difference is if I add the virtual folder "redmine" to the end of the URL on the new server, I don't find the Redmine site.  That is fine.  I actually like not having to type "/redmine" at the end of the URL.  But, I have quite a few people that bookmarked this site using the "/redmine" in the URL.  What I would like is an apache2 rewrite rule that would take this:

```
https://redmine.domain.com/redmine
```

and permanently redirect to this:

```
https://redmine.domain.com
```

How do I do that?

At this point, I have tried figuring out the rewrite syntax myself, but I can't untangle it.  Done a few Google searches looking for examples, but what I'm finding is not matching what I am trying to do.  I suspect I'm not using the right keywords.

EDIT:
@MrWhite - sorry, you are right.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^redmine/(.*)$ https://redmine.domain.com [QSA]
RewriteRule ^redmine$ https://redmine.domain.com [QSA]
```

Here is my whole config:

```
Define REDMINE_SITE=redmine.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${REDMINE_SITE}
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    RailsEnv production
    DocumentRoot /opt/redmine/public

    <Directory "/opt/redmine/public">
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteRule ^redmine/(.*)$ https://${REDMINE_SITE} [QSA]
#    RewriteRule ^redmine$ https://${REDMINE_SITE} [QSA]
#    RewriteRule ^redmine$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =redmine.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The formatting at the end with the last two lines in my VirtualHost tag are not indented because they are added by Let's Encrypt while parsing my port 80 file to build the port 443 file.

Comment: "I have tried figuring out the rewrite syntax myself, but I can't untangle it." - You should include what you have tried. You likely have a minor error, since what you describe sounds like a simple redirect from A to B? Or, there is something else fundamentally wrong with the server, config or something else entirely? But without seeing what you have tried, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have existing mod_rewrite directives then a simple mod_alias `Redirect` directive would probably suffice. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /redmine /
```

(This assumes you are not expecting anything else after `/redmine` in the URL.)

Otherwise, using mod_rewrite, you would need to do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^redmine$ / [R=301,L]
```

This redirects `/redmine` to `/` only. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

Comment: Does not seem to work.